# Getting "Parsing failed" Error for all NRQL queries while posting via HttpURLConnection in Java program

Tags: java, newrelic, nrql

I have written a Java Program to connect to `NewRelic Graphql API` end point https://api.newrelic.com/graphql and successfully able to connect.

- However getting parsing error for the NRQL query.

  ```
  Query is {"query": "SELECT average(duration) FROM Transaction 
  WHERE appName = 'My_Application'"}
  Response Code: 200
  Response Body:
  {"errors":[{"locations":
  [{"column":59,"line":1}],"message":"Parsing failed at `'My_Applic`"}]}
  ```

I am expecting the output, but getting parsing error

Comment: Hi there, can you also share your code

Comment: One thing that jumps out is that the query if not GraphQL format. It is a simple nrql.